# Issue with inserting data on server

Tags: hibernate, hql

i have a hibernate method to save some data into the database its work fine on local server but when its hosted its not inserting results into the database i hosted every (My DB , web services) but its not inserting the valuse. but when i try it on my local host its work fine can any one tell me why is that

```
try {

            session.beginTransaction();

            LabOrder order = (LabOrder) session.get(LabOrder.class, oID);

            Lab lab = (Lab) session.get(Lab.class, lID);

            speciman.setOrderID(order);

            speciman.setLabID(lab);

            session.save(speciman);

            session.getTransaction().commit();

            session.close();

            return true;

        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        }
```

this the code segment that i used to save data

error i am getting

```
Hibernate: select laborder0_.labOrder_ID as labOrder1_1_2_, laborder0_.labOrder_TestID as labOrder2_1_2_, laborder0_.labOrder_SpecimenID as labOrder3_1_2_, laborder0_.labOrder_Location as labOrder4_1_2_, laborder0_.labOrder_Status as labOrder5_1_2_, laborder0_.labOrder_DueDate as labOrder6_1_2_, laborder0_.labOrder_Priority as labOrder7_1_2_, laborder0_.labOrder_Remarks as labOrder8_1_2_, laborder0_.labOrder_LastUpdateUser as labOrder9_1_2_, laborder0_.labOrder_CreateDate as labOrder10_1_2_, laborder0_.labOrder_LastUpdate as labOrder11_1_2_, laborder0_.labOrder_patientID as labOrder12_1_2_, laborder0_.labOrder_CreateUser as labOrder13_1_2_, laborder0_.labOrder_DoctorID as labOrder14_1_2_, testdescri1_.labTestDescription_TestID as labTestD1_0_0_, testdescri1_.labTestDescription_TestName as labTestD2_0_0_, testdescri1_.labTestDescription_TestDescription as labTestD3_0_0_, testdescri1_.labTestDescription_Category as labTestD4_0_0_, testdescri1_.labTestDescription_TestProcedure as labTestD5_0_0_, testdescri1_.labTestDescription_IsSpecimenAvailable as labTestD6_0_0_, testdescri1_.labTestDescription_SpecimenType as labTestD7_0_0_, testdescri1_.labTestDescription_TestResultTableName as labTestD8_0_0_, testdescri1_.labTestdescription_LoincCode as labTestd9_0_0_, testdescri1_.labTestDescription_CreateUser as labTest10_0_0_, testdescri1_.labTestDescription_LastUpdateUser as labTest11_0_0_, testdescri1_.labTestDescription_CreateDate as labTest12_0_0_, testdescri1_.labTestDescription_LastUpdate as labTest13_0_0_, labspecime2_.labSpecimen_ID as labSpeci1_2_1_, labspecime2_.labSpecimen_Status as labSpeci2_2_1_, labspecime2_.labSpecimen_Remarks as labSpeci3_2_1_, labspecime2_.labSpecimen_CollectedBy as labSpeci4_2_1_, labspecime2_.labSpecimen_CollectedDate as labSpeci5_2_1_, labspecime2_.labSpecimen_DeliveredBy as labSpeci6_2_1_, labspecime2_.labSpecimen_DeliveredDate as labSpeci7_2_1_, labspecime2_.labSpecimen_ReceivedBy as labSpeci8_2_1_, labspecime2_.labSpecimen_ReceivedDate as labSpeci9_2_1_, labspecime2_.labSpecimen_CreateUser as labSpec10_2_1_, labspecime2_.labSpecimen_LastUpdateUser as labSpec11_2_1_, labspecime2_.labSpecimen_CreateDate as labSpec12_2_1_, labspecime2_.labSpecimen_LastUpdate as labSpec13_2_1_ from lab_order laborder0_ inner join lab_test_description testdescri1_ on laborder0_.labOrder_TestID=testdescri1_.labTestDescription_TestID left outer join lab_specimen labspecime2_ on laborder0_.labOrder_SpecimenID=labspecime2_.labSpecimen_ID where laborder0_.labOrder_ID=?
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.tuple.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3232)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:871)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:839)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:717)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1785)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2821)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:871)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:808)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:801)
    at lib.driver.lab.driverclasses.SpecimenOfBloodSugarResultServiceDriver.saveSpecimen(SpecimenOfBloodSugarResultServiceDriver.java:28)
    at lib.classes.labmodel.SpecimenOfBloodSugarResultService.addSpecimenOfBlood(SpecimenOfBloodSugarResultService.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Isn't there any exception in your server log?

Comment: Yes, there's an exception but the OP is not printing it as he/she is executing `ex.getMessage();`. That should be `ex.printStacktrace();`

Comment: It would be nice if you place the printStackTrace() statement, redeploy on your server and send the stack trace for more investigation

Comment: actually when i was trying to execute the method is says its successfully inseted into db but in side the b value not inserted    So there is no `ex.getMessage();` message available

Comment: in server log there is a error showing that `LabOrder order = (LabOrder) session.get(LabOrder.class, oID);` getting an null pointer exception , LabOrder class have lots of foreign keys so is there a way too get the LabOrder class , Pls Help

Answer (score 0):

A typical transaction should use the following idiom:

```
Session sess = factory.openSession();
 Transaction tx;
 try {
     tx = sess.beginTransaction();
     //do some work
     ...
     tx.commit();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     throw e;
 }
 finally {
     sess.close();
 }
```

Comment: Ahsan My code work fine on localhost problem is when its deploy to the server